# Allowing "overriding" zero-initialized object with internal linkage

Tags: c, static, language-lawyer, extern, linkage

I'm designing a micro-framework for unit testing and want to be able to provide an ability for client to define a "test suite name". So I have the following header file called `test_suite.h`:

```
static const char *const test_suite_name;

static inline void run_all_tests(void){
    printf("Running ");
    if(!test_suite_name){
        printf("unnamed suite");
    } else {
        printf("%s suite", test_suite_name);
    }
    //run tests
}
```

The intention of this is to allow clients to "override" the `test_suite_name` as follows:

```
#include "test_suite.h"

extern const char *const test_suite_name = "suite1";
```

I think ***the behavior of such usage is well-defined*** since `static const char *const test_suite_name;` constitutes a tentative-definition and then `extern const char *const test_suite_name = "suite1";` constitutes an external definition. There is no linkage disagreement since `6.2.2(p4)`:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a
>   scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31) if
>   the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  the 
>   linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the 
>   same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.

I ran some experiments:

1. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com:

Prints the following error message:

```
error: redefinition of 'const char* const suite_name'
 extern const char *const suite_name = "some suite";
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa1464f186490bf5)

2. https://ideone.com/:

Works completely fine with no warnings produced

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/awC5KJ)

3. `gcc7.4.0` on my machine.

Produces warning:

```
warning: ‘test_suite_name’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
```

***Question:*** Is the behavior of the code shown above well-defined?

I'm pretty sure that the behavior would be undefined if write the following:

```
#include "test_suite.h"

const char *const test_suite_name = "suite1"; //without extern
```

because of `6.2.2(p5)`(emphasize  mine):

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is  determined  exactly  as  if 
>   it  were  declared  with  the  storage-class  specifier `extern`. **If the
>   declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.**

So we would have linkage disagreement between `static const char *const test_suite_name;` with internal linkage and `const char *const test_suite_name = "suite1";` with external linkage.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the discussion here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45977

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Nice catch. The issue is about exactly the case I'm considering. Probably replacing `extern` with `static` is a workaround

Comment: @StephanSchlecht But ommiting storage class specifier entirely is UB. Is there a way to produce a warning in such a case? `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` does not emit it.

Comment: 1. The [coliru DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa1464f186490bf5) probably needs a `-x c` to tell the compiler that the source file is written in C. 2. It seems that ideone does not expose compiler warnings, but it does mean that no warning is produced by the compiler.

Comment: @cpplearner you are right.

Comment: @SomeName You may actually be able to use _static_ instead of _external_. However, if you omit the _static_ specifier, it should even be a compile time error then, not just a warning, or?

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Yes, `static` should be fine since there is no linkage disagreement. No storage class specified compiles with no warnings even though it is UB (linkage disagreement)

Comment: I quickly tried it with gcc on Ubuntu, see answer below. For me it gives an error or did I misunderstand sth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use of static**

You may actually be able to use static instead of external. 
Making a quick test with gcc under Ubuntu:

```
#include "test_suite.h"

static const char *const test_suite_name = "huhu";

int main() {
      run_all_tests();
      return 0;
}
```

If I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra mytest.c -o mytest
```

it gives as output:

```
Running huhu suite
```

**Omitting static**

If you accidentally forget to specify static it should give a compile time error then. So if I change this line to:

```
const char *const test_suite_name = "huhu";
```

and try to compile it like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra mytest2.c -o mytest2
```

this error message will be displayed:

```
mytest2.c:3:19: error: non-static declaration of ‘test_suite_name’ follows static declaration
 const char *const test_suite_name = "huhu";
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from mytest2.c:1:
test_suite.h:3:26: note: previous declaration of ‘test_suite_name’ was here
 static const char *const test_suite_name;
```

Since it is an error it is also output if you compile with:

```
gcc mytest2.c -o mytest2
```

**Screenshot of Error Message**

[image: Screenshot with Error Message]

Comment: Anyway the case with no storage-class specified is not a constraint violatio so no diagnostic message is required.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The consumer of your framework should *not* omit the static, because then the behavior is undefined due to the standard, which genereally should be better avoided. Here §6.2.2(7) applies: _If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined._ There are also for sure C compilers which would compile this without error message. But wouldn't this be a problem on consumer side?